# Checking is string in one of the values of list property?

Tags: c#

I have a public class.

```
public class StoreItems 
{
    public string itemName;
    public string itemPrice;
    public string itemQuantity;
}
```

I have a list.

```
public List <StoreItems> itemData = new List<StoreItems> ();
```

The user will enter an item name and im supposed to check if that item name is already in my itemData's itemName.

My current code is something like this

```
if (itemData.Find(x => x.itemData.Equals(userInput))
 {
  //already in list
 }
else
 {
 //add data
 }
```

However, I'm getting an error saying itemData cannot be implicitly converted to bool. Tips would be appreciated

Comment: `itemData` is of course a complex object, whereas `userInput` is just a `string`. How would you compare those? In particular how should your program know that in order to determine equality the `itemName`-property of your object should be used not any other property? This is like comparing apples and oranges.

Answer (score 10):

You can achieve this easily with LINQ.

```
if(itemData.Any(data => data.itemName == userInput))
```

[`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) checks all items of an `IEnumerable` whether they match a given predicate, or not.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have a `List<>` and already tried to use [`List<T>.Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx), this works too:

```
StoreItems matchingItem = itemData.Find(si => si.itemName == userInput);
if (matchingItem != null)
{
    //already in list
}
else
{
    //add data
}
```

Of course this works only if there is no null-reference in the list.